# Can't Clone a User Profile?

Tags: users, user-profile

I have a user profile all setup with *all* settings the way I want them. I want to copy the entire configured profile to a new user account.

This is what I'm doing (user is already added to system):

1. Log out, switch to terminal, `service gdm stop`.
2. `mkdir /home/newuser`
3. `cp -a /home/olduser/* /home/newuser/`
4. `chown newuser:newuser /home/newuser -R`
5. `service gdm start`

Then I log in as newuser. When I log in, the desktop looks like a brand new user profile and not the customized profile that I copied.

I want *everything* in the new profile. The theme, where the docks are located and configured, desktop icons, Firefox favorites, etc.

Any idea why this isn't working? I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. Apparently cp /* skips dot files.

You have to explicitly copy dot files with:

```
cp -a /home/olduser/.* /home/newuser/
```

And to copy everything do both:

```
cp -a /home/olduser/* /home/newuser/
cp -a /home/olduser/.* /home/newuser/
```

Comment: The `bash` shell has an option `dotglob` (you can set it with `shopt`—see the `bash` manual for more info) which, if set, makes `*` match files starting with a dot too.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to "accept" your own solution so that this question is marked as answered...

Comment: +1 for the dotglob comment. There's a waiting period on accepting answers too soon...

Answer (score 4):

You will need to do more then that.

```
sudo mv /home/new_user /home/new_user.bak
sudo cp -R /home/old_user /home/new_user
sudo chown -R new_user:new_user /home/new_user
```

Log into the new user account. If all is working, delete the backup

```
sudo rm -rf /home/new_user.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to clone my current profile to a new user. My home directory was large, almost 100 GB. [bodhi.zazen's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100252/cant-clone-a-user-profile) worked for me, but it took half a day of false starts before I got it right. Here's an expanded annotated version of his answer (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04):

#### Create new user

I just used the desktop UI: System Settings > User Accounts > Unlock > + New User

#### Backup new user home directory

Now on to the command line:

```
sudo mv /home/new_user /home/new_user.bak
```

#### Copy profile to new user home directory

If you have a large profile, I'd recommend using rsync and excluding some directories. Here's an example of what I ran:

```
time sudo rsync -av --progress \
  --exclude='VirtualBox VMs' \
  --exclude='.cache/deja-dup' \
  --exclude='.local/share/Trash' \
  --exclude='nltk_data' \
  --exclude='Downloads' \
  /home/klenwell/ /home/new_user
```

A couple notes:

- `--exclude` directories are subdirectories of the source dir `/home/klenwell/`.
- Note the end slash on `/home/klenwell/`. Miss it and you'll end up with `/home/new_user/klenwell`.

I'd recommend a couple quick test runs before walking off. Use `--dry-run` and even run it once or twice cutting it short to double check everything is going where you expect. With exclusions, I cut my home directory in half but it still took an hour to copy.

#### Make new user owner of home directory

```
time sudo chown -R new_user:new_user /home/new_user
```

Took 5 minutes to complete in my case.

#### Log in with your new user

If you try to log in with your new user and Ubuntu just keeps kicking you back to the login prompt, you probably forgot the previous step.

If you successfully log in, now you can wipe out your old backup:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/new_user.bak
```

#### References

- [Can't Clone a User Profile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100252/cant-clone-a-user-profile)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193584/copy-folder-recursively-excluding-some-folders